# onBackPressed How to return backbutton press to android

Tags: android

I have a popupWindow which I close in OnBackPressed in my activity. But when the popupWindow is not visible but back button is pressed then my activity should be closed and control should go to the home screen.

I do not have a way to do that as there is no return code in onBackPressed, Any clues?

Comment: please show us the code You have done

Answer (score 1):

Try to check whether your popupWindow visible or not, if it not then DO NOT call `super.onBackPressed();` in you onBackPress method, that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to link these both:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {



             finish();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my pseudocode. I think you just need a way to judge whether your popup is still there

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (popupWindow  != null && popupWindow.isVisible()) {
        popupWindow.dismiss();
        popupWindow = null;
        return;
    }

    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this...I think this is what you have to do

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        i
        if (null != popUpWindow && popUpWindow.isShowing()) {

            // dismiss the popup window

            popUpWindow.dismiss();

        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
                    finish();
        }
    }
```